# How to apply control points in LiDAR?

Tags: lidar, software-recommendations, ground-control

I am new to LiDAR point clouds and I have a big issue. I have LiDAR data for 30 km and I have 5 - 6 control points.

My point cloud is inaccurate (have averagely 3-4 m error in xy and 50 m error on Z) and I want to use the control points so that I can minimize this error. I have read about LAStool and FUSION, I just get information about shifting all point cloud in x,y,z but nothing about control points application.

Is there any software that can help me to apply control points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always import the lidar data back into the software you used to initially process the point cloud and add the control points there. For example, this is a step that would be done in Leica Cyclone. If you do not have that option, I'd recommend poking around the LAStools Google Group and asking this question again on there. I cannot find a link right now, but I think Martin (the LAStools developer) actually has a tutorial for this specific problem.

Comment: I will go to LAStools Google Group, it looks like all the LiDAR guru are there